# Bash script to continuously check for a difference

Tags: bash

I have 2 c++ binaries and a java class file ready to be interpreted.

```
debug_script.sh //my script file
gen
exe
prob.class
```

In debug_script, my first goal is to execute `gen`. This prints an output string to stdout, lets call it `EXPR`. The string then goes into `exe` and `prob.class` both read stdin delimited by a newline. In pseudocode/broken-bash this would look like:

```
./exe < EXPR
java -cp . prob.class < EXPR
```

Both `exe` and `prob.class` generate an integer stdout, I want to compare the two integers to see if they both are equal in an infinite while loop (repeat the entire process of generating `EXPR` and feeding it to the 2 programs).

The loop should break and store `EXPR` in a file, or just echo it, in the event if the two returned integeres from `gen` and `prob.class` are different.

Comment: Note that you probably shouldn't do this "continuously" at all. Better to use `inotifywait` to tell you when one of the files changes, and only *then* run a comparison of their output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the output in a variable and pass it to your other programs like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while : ; do

    gen_out=$(gen)
    intone=$(./exe <<<"$gen_out")
    inttwo=$(java -cp . prob.class <<<"$gen_out")

    if [[ $intone != $inttwo ]]; then
        echo "gen output when exe and prob.class differ: $gen_out"
        echo "exe output: $intone"
        echo "prob.class output: $inttwo"
        break
    fi

done
```

`<<<` is called here string. See [bash manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would create an infinite loop:
        `while true; do {code}; done`
So in your case:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    while true; do

    EXPR=$(./gen)
    val1=$(./exe < $EXPR)
    val2=$(java -cp . prob.class < $EXPR)
    if [ $val1 = $val2 ];then
    exit
    fi
    echo $EXPR
    sleep 1

    done
```